# PCIe rescan from kernel device driver

Tags: linux-kernel

I've got a PCIe board with a FPGA and my own kernel device driver.

After the FPGA has been loaded, I need to rescan the PCIe tree.
I used the regular /sys/bus/pci/devices/xxx/remove + /sys/bus/pci/rescan to do that.

The access to these files must be done with root privileges and it could be a pain.

Is it possible to do the rescan from my kernel device driver ?

I tried to call pci_remove_bus () + pci_rescan_bus () in the open call but I've got a kernel panic.

Where can I find an example of pci_remove_bus () + pci_rescan_bus () use ?

Thanks,

Fred

Comment: You have to hold a bus lock. Otherwise it works like you described.

Comment: Check `bus_rescan_store()` implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine. I just added `pci_stop_and_remove_bus_device()` before this sequence.

Comment: Btw, consider to use / implement PCI switch from FPGA side so you can leverage PCI hotplug mechanism and you don't need to take care of this manually.

Comment: I don't know this mechanism, how can it be done ?

Comment: @Fred - I have a similar requirement but having an issue with `pci_rescan_bus()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549023/pci-rescan-bus-doesnt-rescan-pci-bus-in-linux